# Printf function who returning an array of int

Tags: c, printf, malloc

I'm trying this exercice but I don't know how to printf my function in main.
Exercice: 
1) Write a function who returning an int tab with all values between min and max

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *ft_range(int min, int max)
{
    int len;
    int *tab;

    len = min;
    while (len < max)
        len++;

    tab = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*tab) * len + 1);

    while (min < max)
    {
        *tab = min;
        min++;
    }
    return(tab);
}

int main()
{
    ft_range(0, 10);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `main` probably needs to know `len` too.

Comment: How many values are there between 0 and 10? So you don't need a loop to determine `len`.

Comment: You correctly allocate your table, but you always only fill the first element. Try something like `tab[i++]= min++;`

Comment: You return `tab`. So in `main` you should write something like `int *tab=  ft_range(0, 10);` Now you can use a loop to print each value.

Comment: `ft_range(0, 10)` calls the function and throws the result away right after that. It's like writing `sin(PI/4);` it calls the sinus function and does nothing with the result.

Comment: BTW: the `ft_range` function is not quite correct, there is a small but obvious bug. Exercise for you: find it.

Comment: @Eric Ling Min and max of what?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> returning an int tab with all values between min and max

Depending on the idea of "between", it is an open question if the end values should be included.  Given OP's mis-coded +1  in `sizeof(*tab) * len + 1`, I'll go with the idea both ends should be included.

**Miscalculation of `len`**

Rather than loop, simply subtract

```
//len = min;
//while (len < max)
//    len++;
len = max - min + 1;
```

**Allocation miscalculated**

Good to use `sizeof *pointer`, yet the + 1 makes little sense.  If anything the `... * len + 1` should have been `... * (len + 1)`.  Yet the +1 is handled with the above fix.  Also cast not needed in C.

```
// tab = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*tab) * len + 1);
tab = malloc(sizeof *tab * len);
```

**Wrong assignment**

Code repeatedly assigned the same `*tab` location.

```
//while (min < max)
//{
//    *tab = min;
//    min++;
//}
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  tab[i - min] = i;
}
```

**No allocation error checking nor `min, max` validation**

**Potential for `int` overflow with `mix - min`**

**Be sure to free allocations**

---

Alternative

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *ft_range(int min, int max) {
  if (min > max) {
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t len = (size_t)max - min + 1;

  int *tab = malloc(sizeof *tab * len);
  if (tab == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tab[i] = int(min + i);
  }

  return tab;
}

int main() {
    int mn = 0;
    int mx = 10;
    int *ft = ft_range(mn, mx);
    if (ft) {
      int *p = ft;
      for (int i = mn; i <= mx; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *p++);
      }
      free(ft);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- inside "ft_range", when you are trying to calculate the length the array needs to do, all you have to do is subtract the minimum from the maximum. what you did is much slower and unnecessary.
- when allocating memory, you did not need to add a "+1" at the end. you may have seen it done in other examples, but it does not apply here.
- the "while" loop inside "ft_range" needs to have a "<=" sign, otherwise it will stop before it reaches the "max" value.
- when adding a value to the "tab" int array, you are always doing so by dereferencing it (putting a "*" before it), so every one of your values will come on the first position of the array and overwrite themselves. you need to have another "int i" to keep track of the current index of the array.
- make sure to free the memory you allocated with "malloc" after you finish your enumeration. it does not matter right now, but if you ever get to writing more complex programs you will need to do so to keep the performance up, which can be critical.

here's a working code, with a few comments (i'm shit at comments, if you don't understand them, just ask me bro)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *ft_range(int min, int max)
{
    int len;
    int * tab;

    len = max-min;

    tab = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*tab) * len);

    // create an index to track the position inside "tab"
    int i = 0;

    // sign needs to be "<=" so it does not stop before it reaches the max value
    while (min <= max)
    {
        tab[i] = min;
        // ++ needs to come before so the variable's value is updated right here
        ++min;
        // increase the i index to the next position in "tab"
        ++i;
    }

    return(tab);
}

int main()
{
        int min = 5;
int max = 10;
int len = max-min;
int * range = ft_range(min, max);

for(int i = 0; i <= len; ++i)
    {
        // %d = integer
        // \n = move to next line
        printf("%d\n", range[i]);
    }

    getchar();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `len` is off by 1.  Consider `ft_range(42,42)`.  Also deeper: `max-min` may overflow.

Comment: yeah there's things that can be improved, but it's OPs code, so i wanted to get him started.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly allocate memory to the table, you just need to printf the value in your main by using a loop trough your tab, i write this code who work perfectly.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

int *ft_range(int min, int max)
{
    int *ptr;
    int mi;
    int i;
    int range;

    range = (max - min);
    mi = min;
    ptr = NULL;
    if (min > max)
        return (NULL);
    else
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * range);
    i = 0;
    while (i < range)
    {
        ptr[i] = mi + i;
        i++;
    }
    return (ptr);
}
// #include <stdio.h>
// int  main()
// {
//  //int i = 0;
//  int min = 1;
//  int max = 30;

//  while(min < max)
//  {
//      printf("%d\n", *ft_range(min, max));
//      min++;
//  }
// }
```