# Allocate 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have a segment fault int this exercice.

Instruction:

• Write an ft_ultimate_range function which allocates and assigns an int array. This int table will contain all values ​​between min and max.
• Min included - max excluded.
• If the min value is greater than or equal to the max value, range will point to NULL.
• The range size will be returned (or 0 in the event of a problem).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_ultimate_range(int **range, int min ,int max)
{
    int len;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    len = max - min;
    if (min >= max)
    {
        *range = NULL;
        return(0);
    }

    **range = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
    while (min < max)
    {
        range[0][i] = min;
        i++;
        min++;
    }
    return(len);
}

int main()
{
    int min;
    int max;
    int **range = NULL;

    min = 0;
    max = 10;
    printf("%d\n", ft_ultimate_range(range, min, max));
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How is this so different from yesterday's [Printf function who returning an array of int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61870571/2410359)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**range = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
```

This line raises the warning when i compile your code:

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Never ignore the warning from the compiler.

`malloc` function returns a pointer, why do you cast it to `int` value ?

You want 2D array, but i seems that is matrix `1 x len`, it's 1D array (vector).

OK, forget the 2D or 1D array (vector). If you want to use double pointer in your code, you have allocate for it first.

```
// this line should be in main function
range = malloc(sizeof(int *));
if(!range) {
   return -1;
}
// this line before while loop
range[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*len);
if(!range[0]) {
   return -1;
}
```

If you want a matrix "M*N", you can allocate the pointer as below:

```
// allocate double pointer
range = malloc(sizeof(int *)*M);
if(!range) {
   return -1;
}

// then using a loop to allocate the pointers:
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
   range[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
   if(!range[i]) {
     return -1;
   }
}
```

Do not forget to free the pointer when you do not need to use (`free(range[i]` then `free(range)`).

Answer (score 1):

As you have guessed your allocation is wrong

by writing

```
**range = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
```

you meant to assign to the dereference of the dereference of range (NULL)

range = NULL
*range = whatever value is at offset 0 
**range = whatever value is at the address from the value read at address 0

please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for writing the allocator

it would boil down to:

```
array = malloc( sizeof(int[rows][cols]) );
```

but in your case you want to return the array as a pass by ref var

```
int main() {
    int **array;
    ft_ultimate_range(&array)
}

int ft_ultimate_range(int ***array) {
   *array = malloc( sizeof(int[rows][cols]) );
}
```

## BUT

your code is kind of not using the full 2d array and the function is not returning it:

```
    while (min < max)
    {
        range[0][i] = min;
        i++;
        min++;
    }
```

you are only using one row here, and not even using the data in `range` after that, one would think the code to be irrelevant, as you are only returning `len`.

Comment: They do not really want a 2D array, just a pointer to a 1D array. Initially, they want an `int *` to point to where the data will be stored, and then they need an `int **` so the function can pass the `int *` back. `range[0][i]` is just a way of writing `(*range)[i]`.

Comment: the author code is confusing in its intent, might be a work in progress, and just placeholder loop

Comment: No, we saw this in another question recently. These students are working on an assignment that requires them to return an array of ‘int` via an `int **` parameter.

Comment: Thanks or the insight @EricPostpischil